# City shapefile for free

Tags: shapefile, point, download, data

I am looking for a simple point shapefile which indicates where the cities of the world are. 
I cannot seem to find one which is free of charge and meets my requirements.
Ive got this one: http://techcenter.jefferson.kctcs.edu/data/ but I want smaller cities too...

Any ideas where I can get them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Populated Places 1:10m (Natural Earth) Shapefile**

7343 Cities

[image]

Download from
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/
(Populated Places)

Terms of Use
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/about/terms-of-use/

> No permission is needed to use Natural Earth. Crediting the authors is
>   unnecessary.
>
> However, if you wish to cite the map data, simply use one of the
>   following.
>
> Short text: Made with Natural Earth

Answer (score 3):

Are there any parameters on the cities you want?

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) might be a good resource. Under their [tools page](http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html) there is a GeoNames csv file to shapefile converter. It might take a little bit of work and sifting through the data to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Must it be a shapefile? Google Maps offer something like you asked as a kml file (kmz in fact, which is just a zip containing a kml), at https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zMlf_4RO8x7E.kllT447wz1Ws&msa=0&ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=8.407168,165.9375&spn=130.849955,280.898438&z=2&source=embed

Comment: Nope. I can work with a kml/kmz file. But the link you gave me has an even coarser resolution...

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Hub offers [this data](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esri::world-cities/explore?location=3.620649%2C-178.464838%2C2.65) with 2,540 records. The POP_RANK field looks useful for classifying the cities.